# "There are fish of every hue." For different kinds of fish, should fish be in plural form here?

Tags: phrases, syntactic-analysis, grammatical-number, verb-agreement, sentence-patterns

- *In the Caribbean waters, there are fish of every hue.*

Since one is talking about different kinds of fish, should *fish* be in marked plural form (*fishes*) here?

Comment: You can use either. They way you have it now is perfectly grammatical and idiomatic. As would using the plural be.

Comment: In the above example "fish" *is* plural.

Comment: Hot Licks is correct here. _In the Amazonian skies, there are bird of every hue._ is of course incorrect. ' ... there are ... ' requires a plural-form count noun usage. But unlike 'bird', the plural form of 'fish' is either 'fishes' or invariant 'fish'. General reference. Whether 'fish' is more common and 'fishes' preferred by some for 'different types of fish' is a different matter.

Comment: My reading of this question is not that the poster is unaware that the plural of fish may in some cases be either _fish_ or _fishes_, but that the poster wonders whether, in the particular case where multiple varieties of fish are being discussed, the plural **must** be _fishes_. I am not aware of a general-reference source that addresses this specific question, and, therefore, I think it is a legitimate question for EL&U .

Comment: Sven has rightly understood my question. Anyway, other comments were also informative enough for me. Thanks Dan, Hot Licks and Edwin.

Comment: @SvenYargs How tolerant the modern ear is of *fishes* may vary by age and background. I'm not 100% certain that—even when multiple kinds of fish are being discussed—one “must” “always” say *fishes*. You **should** be able to do the same thing as we do with mass nouns or *pluralia tantum*: “Xes of Y” partitive constructions marking the plural on X not Y like ***kinds of** fish/deer/sheep/cattle/rice/wheat* and ***types of** fish/deer/sheep/cattle/rice/wheat* seem perfectly serviceable to me, as do  attributive uses like *fish species* or *deer species* or *cattle breeds* or *wheat cultivars*.

Comment: @tchrist: I think we agree on this. In my fishing days, I would never have said "We caught three **fish** today—five perch, three bass, and one crappie" or "We caught three **fishes** today—five perch, three bass, and one crappie." Instead, I would have said "We caught three **kinds of fish** today—five perch, three bass, and one crappie." The framing "kinds of fish" would have obviated the need to say "three fish" or "three fishes"—although saying "three fish" and then listing nine seems very odd. Alternatively, I might have said "We caught nine fish today," meaning nine individual creatures.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The plural form of "fish" is "fish" ("fishes" is also an accepted plural, but it is less common). The same is true for

- bison
- sheep
- deer
- moose
- aircraft

and a number of other words. You can find some more examples here: [Nouns with the same plural and singular forms](https://www.focus.olsztyn.pl/en-grammar-nouns-singular-plural.html)

Answer (score 2):

Further to Sven Yargs's comment, to explain why many books have  *fishes* rather than *fish* in their [titles](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=fishes):

> **What is the plural of fish?**
>
> The word "fish" is singular and plural for a single species: one Green Sunfish, two Green Sunfish.
> Ichthyologists (people who study fishes) use "fishes" to refer to more
> than one species, four different species of sunfishes, fishes of the
> Gulf of Maine.  [G. Helfman and B. Collette; *Fishes: The Animal
> Answer Guide*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Fishes/G8jLeHpIoMcC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=fish%20versus%20fishes&pg=PA1&printsec=frontcover) (2011)

> Fish versus fishes. By convention, "fish" refers to one or more
> individual of a single species. "Fishes" is used when discussing more
> than one species, regardless of the number of individuals involved.
> [G. Helfman et al.; *The Diversity of Fishes: Biology, Evolution, and Ecology*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Diversity_of_Fishes/FyehAR6hsUUC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=fish%20versus%20fishes&pg=PA5&printsec=frontcover) (2009)

Comment: +1. To this useful and succinct answer I would add that _fish_ as a plural also commonly appears in instances where undifferentiated members of the classification "fish" (that is, fish qua fish) are under discussion, whether they are all of the same species or not. Thus "There are many fish in the sea" refers (often figuratively) to the vast number of fish of all kinds that live in the sea, but "There are many fishes in the sea" is likelier to be used to refer to the many types of fish within the superclass Osteichthyes that live in large bodies of saltwater.