# Is it "three types of fish" or "three types of fishes"?

Tags: irregular-plurals

I have learnt that the plural of *fish* is still *fish*.

However, if we refer to different types of fish, we can use *fishes*; for example:

> The aquarium has three fishes: goldfish, carp, and guppy.

If that is the case, do we say *three types of fish* or *three types of fishes*?

Comment: fishes is old fashioned and poetica*l*.

Comment: There's something fishy about this question.

Comment: Related (at least): [Types of things vs types of thing](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/5539/2303)

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/586484/2085).

Answer (score 4):

## *one ﬁsh, two ﬁsh,
red ﬁsh, blue ﬁsh*

There’s only one realistic choice that people make here, in practice not theory, as shown by [this ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=types+of+fish%2C+types+of+fishes&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3):

[image: ngram plotting types of ﬁsh vs types of ﬁshes]

That chart shows you that **what people actually write** is overwhelmingly *types of ﬁsh*. Virtually never do they actually write *types of ﬁshes*. Look at the red line compared with the blue line. There’s just no contest between the two. Blue wins.

Theoretical arguments about acceptability are meaningless in the face of actual data showing what it is that people are using in the real world. You should do what they do.

If it helps, notice that we use *kinds of dog*, not **kinds of dogs*.

Comment: [Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=breeds+of+dog%2C+breeds+of+dogs%2C+kinds+of+dog%2C+kinds+of+dogs%2C+types+of+dog%2C+types+of+dogs&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) says that *breeds of dogs, kinds of dogs,* and *types of dogs* are all more common than the expressions with *dog*.

Comment: ........ dogfishes.

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/586484/2085).

Answer (score 1):

If you have 3 goldfish and 2 herring, you have

- 5 fish
- 2 fishes
- 2 types of fish

See [usage notes on wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fish#Usage_notes)

> When referring to two or more **kinds of fish**, the plural is fishes.

Comment: The usual plural of _fish_, like the usual plurals of _salmon, trout, deer,_ and _sheep_, is zero. I.e, it's "2 fish".

Comment: fishes of the sea: See the Bible, for example.

Comment: I would use "5 fish", "2 types of fish" or "2 types of fishes". I would not use "2 fishes". I have upvoted to make the answer score zero as the reference is useful.

Comment: But [Britannica](https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/eb/qa/Using-Fish-as-Singular-and-Plural#:~:text=When%20you%20are%20talking%20about%20more%20than%20one%20kind%20or,different%20fishes%20in%20our%20pond.) has: 'When you are talking about more than one kind or species of fish, both 'fish' and 'fishes' are ok to use.' Some dictionaries say that 'fishes' is merely a rarer alternative, while some pundits, biologists, and aged and religious people say that 'fishes' is to be used, usually 'for _types_ of fish'.